# How to read unsigned int in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm writing a binary string from the server like this:

```
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
echo $data = pack('C*', 0, 10, 100, 127, 128, 200, 250, 255, 256);
```

and reading it with js and jDataView lib this way:

```
$.get('/get', function(text) {
    var view = new jDataView(text);

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        console.log(i, view.getUint8(i));
    }
});
```

The problem is that I can only read the values that are less than 128. jDataView uses `getCharCode` at to read `Uint` and it returns 65533 for each of the bigger values.

How to I get the values in js?

Comment: You mean `.charCodeAt()`, right?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas It is, but the question is not about it, I suppose.

Comment: @raina77ow Yes, I understand that. However, in comments, we are allowed to address issues that are not directly related to the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine when you change the headers sent (by PHP file) with...

`header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=x-user-defined')`

Without this header (and tweaking of how XHR response should be processed; [this article](http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/jquery-binary-ajax.html) describes the process in details) it's the `text` value that becomes messed up: all 'invalid' (> 127) characters will be literally replaced by `'\uFFFD'` ones.

Of course, it's not possible to extract the original values from these characters, so it's not a bug of jDataView, in my opinion.